# Getting Fatal Error when using PHP upload when connecting to database

Tags: php, ms-access

Created code years ago to upload images to the server and inserting name into database. Worked fine until recently when the servers PHP were updated to 7.2.

I now receive the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function odbc_connect() in \*****.*****.LOCAL\DOMAINSW**********\user\htdocs\adminVehicleImages.php:23
>   Stack trace:
>   0 {main}
>     thrown in \*****.*****.LOCAL\DOMAINSW**********\user\htdocs\adminVehicleImages.php on line 23

```php
    <?php
    /****************************************************************/
    /* This script is used to upload and delete images for listings */
    /*                                                              */
    /* GET 'id'    = id of listing                                  */
    /* GET 'index' = position of image (1-4)                        */
    /*                                                              */
    /* Include FILES 'file' to upload/replace jpg image             */
    /* Include POST 'delete' to remove image                        */
    /****************************************************************/

    if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']!='https://*****.com/adminlist.asp' && $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']!='http://www.*****.com/adminlist.asp') die('did not come from admin page'); //do not continue if the request did not come from the admin page

    if(!isset($_GET['id']) || !isset($_GET['index']) || ( !isset($_FILES['file']) && !isset($_POST['delete']) )) die('does not have required parameters'); // do not continue if all the required parameters are not supplied

    if($_GET['index']<1 || $_GET['index']>4) die('index out of bounds'); //index out of bounds ... valid 1,2,3,4 

    //db connection
    $dbFile='ow_db\*****_database.mdb';
    if(!file_exists($dbFile)) die('could not find db'); //could not find db
    //print_r($_SERVER);
    //$db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$dbFile; Uid=; Pwd=;");
    $db = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=$dbFile;",'','');
    //print_r(odbc_errormsg());

    //clean variables
    $id=(int)$_GET['id'];
    $index=(int)$_GET['index'];
    $uploadDir='images/';
    $uploadExt='.JPG';

    $fileName=$uploadDir.$id.'_'.$index.$uploadExt;

    //choose an action
     if(isset($_POST['delete'])){//remove file if exists
        if(file_exists($fileName))
        unlink($fileName);

        //update the db
        //$db->query("UPDATE tbl*****List SET Pic$index = ' ' WHERE ID=$id");
        odbc_exec($db,"UPDATE tbl*****List SET Pic$index = ' ' WHERE ID=$id");

        echo 'Image removed';
        echo '<script>setTimeout(function(){window.location.href="adminlist.asp";},1000)</script>'; //go back to the previous page after 1,000ms (1 second)
    }
    else if(isset($_FILES['file'])){ // upload or replace image

        //validate uploaded image
        if($_FILES['file']['size'] > 5000000){echo 'image too large'; return false;} //make sure size is lees than 5MB
        if(getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']) === false){echo 'not an image'; return false;} //make sure it is internally an image
        if(strToLower(substr($_FILES['file']['name'],-4))!='.jpg'){echo 'not jpg image'; return false;} //make sure the file is jpg

        //remove file if exists
        if(file_exists($fileName))
            unlink($fileName);

        //upload image
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $fileName);

        //update the db
        $index2=$id.'_'.$index;
        //$db->query("UPDATE tbl*****List SET Pic$index = '$index2.JPG' WHERE ID=$id");
        odbc_exec($db,"UPDATE tbl*****List SET Pic$index = '$index2.JPG' WHERE ID=$id");

        echo 'Image uploaded';
        echo '<script>setTimeout(function(){window.location.href="adminlist.asp";},1000)</script>'; //go back to the previous page after 1,000ms (1 second)
    }

    else echo 'nothing to do';
    ?>
```

This is line of code that returns the error:

```php
$db = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=$dbFile;",'','');
```

Is this a PHP error or a database connect error? Any help would be really appreciated it.

Comment: `Call to undefined function odbc_connect()` This indicates that you do not have the ODBC module loaded. You'll likely need to add `extension=odbc.dll` or similar to your php.ini file.

Comment: Thank you! Will contact the server admin and let you know how I get on!